# What is the title of this fable where a mongoose is getting married but takes too long to collect a dowry?

Tags: identification-request, folk-tales

My friend described a possible fable to me that they read as  a child. They recall it being a picture book that was a fable/folk tale that had a weasel/mongoose type character. The main character gets engaged and sets out to collect his friends and dowry for the wedding. Among the friends he finds on the way are a tortoise and a boa/python. He waits for each of his friends to complete their own tasks (boa eats an antelope, tortoise waits for log to break down so he can get over it). Because of this, he returns to his village a very long time later. His bride has married someone else as he took so long.

Comment: Cultural details could be useful for this one. Was the story written in English, another language, translated? Which country, or which part of the world, was it written/set in? The latter is especially important because it helps to narrow down the types of animal involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Traveling to Tondo: A Tale of the Nkundo of Zaire](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5493308.Traveling_to_Tondo_A_Tale_of_the_Nkundo_of_Zaire)

> On his way to his wedding, with his friends as attendants, a civet cat
>   meets with extraordinary and unexpected delays.

Reviews on Goodreads mention Bowane (the civet cat), Embenga (the pigeon), Nguma (the python) and Ulu (the tortoise) and that the journey took several years, when they arrived the bride-to-be has married someone else.